# VLOOKUP, using an undefined substring as the lookup value

Tags: excel, vba, substring, vlookup

I have been thinking about this one for a while now; I am asking if there is a way of doing this purely using Excel formulas. There are few things more frustrating to me than creating VBA code to create a function that already exists.

I have a table with a column "Description" and a column "Country". I use "Description" as the lookup value of a VLOOKUP function to find its "Country" from an auxiliary table. The problem is that the value that would match in the auxiliary table can be anywhere within the "Description". The picture in the link is probably a better explanation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlV28.png

So... easily done with an Excel function (or combination of), or do I need to create a VBA function for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have access to the new lambda function, this would be a good use case. Check this: https://youtu.be/L7s6Dni1dG8 if not, look for fuzzy match within Power Query

Answer (score 1):

In B2 enter: `=INDEX($E$1:$E$7,LARGE(IF(IFERROR(FIND($D$1:$D$7,A1)>0,0),ROW($D$1:$D$7)-ROW($D$1)+1),1))` and use the fill handle to drag down.

Note: this breaks easily and may give unwanted results if say, you have an empty cell in column D!

(What it's doing, is doing a lookup **from** column D **to** column A, and seeing if the result matches the corresponding row in column A...

[image]

(not the best solution, IMO, but it would work for me)